# Can I express $\sqrt{x}$ as $Q(x)$ where Q(x) is a first degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Can I express $\sqrt{x}$ as $Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is a first degree polynomial?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Are you asking if $\sqrt{x}=ax+b$ for some $a,b$? Then the answer is no.

Comment: You can approximate it, in some way, at best. Is that what you mean?

Comment: you can use the identity $ (\sqrt x  +1)(\sqrt x -1)=x-1 $ to approximate the root by a rational function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No polynomial of any degree. To expand on @Jose Garcia's comment, for every $x\geqslant0$,
$$\sqrt{x}=1+\cfrac{x-1}{2+\cfrac{x-1}{2+\cfrac{x-1}{2+\cdots}}}$$